# Why isn't Importrange() data working in function?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I've looked up every solution to this question and tried them all with no luck.

Im importing coordinates from another page and determining if they're between a range using the =if(and() function. But it seems like the and() will only accept 3 and() statements max. And some of the functions don't even register in the functions. I cant figure out why.

All cells are formatted as numbers
tried various combinations

Feel free to play with the function. I've been working on it for 3 days and still can't find a solution. Can anyone help?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZSDju3hRyGyRfFhHJT2PLQ3DBvcfOAT1ZvNxB-J0DQ/edit?usp=sharing

Take a look at the green higlighted rows. They all fall within the Green highlights range but nothing.,,

Comment: your imported values are formated as plain text - that's why. `"one"` is not equal to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A*1, SORT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(F2:G="",,F2:G&"♦"&E2:E)), "♦"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0)), 2, 1))=
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B*1, SORT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(H2:I="",,H2:I&"♦"&E2:E)), "♦"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0)), 2, 1)), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A*1, SORT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(F2:G="",,F2:G&"♦"&E2:E)), "♦"),
 "where Col2 is not null", 0)), 2, 1)), ))
```

[image]

---

### !! however

in case of possible overlaps you will need to use this formula and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((A2*1>=F$2:F)*(A2*1<=G$2:G)*(B2*1>=H$2:H)*(B2*1<=I$2:I), E$2:E, )))
```

[image: 0]

---

your importrange should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("1ol7DTYZcwZVZk6WhfCLQ1JBt3_3QIEXEC5TkfEerCMw", "CheckinForm!I2:J30"), 
 "where not Col1 = '#ERROR!' and Col1 is not null", 0), "^: ", )*1)
```

[image]

Comment: WOW !! I'll have to spend some time to go through and understand how it works. But just for now.  i'm uploading new data to the array and it's not updating the in/out column. Any thought why?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? which formula did you use?

Comment: Same sheet. It uses arrayfunction to place values in X & Y. But your function to sort does not follow the new entries down the sheet. Also I think I should have mentioned that this is a dynamic array, not changing but adding constantly.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZSDju3hRyGyRfFhHJT2PLQ3DBvcfOAT1ZvNxB-J0DQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It works like a charm. I guess another question is how do I add another field/range of numbers into the locations? Simply add the numbers below the other existing characters?

Comment: It's gota be something Im doing. It's not reading new ranges and new entries. Maybe it's how I'm entering the ranges into the spreadsheet? Copy and paste vs typing them in directly? :/
@player0
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ol7DTYZcwZVZk6WhfCLQ1JBt3_3QIEXEC5TkfEerCMw/edit?usp=sharing